# jQuery graph/plot plugin with drag and drop capabilities on the elements?

Tags: jquery, graph, plot, flot, drag-and-drop

The short version:

I'm looking for a graph/plotting/grid/diagram plugin just like the [flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/) plugin but with drag and drop capabilities on the elements. Any suggestions?

The long version:

I'm building a tool for management of work processes and assignments. I'm imagining a graph with time on the x-axis and employees on the y-axis. The graph then displays assignments for all the employees at the specific time spans. Then you can see for example if any assignments are over lapsing each other, how long the assignments are or if any employees have any major holes in their time line etc. That part is relatively easy. The hard part is that I want to enable drag and drop on the assignment elements, so that if two assignments are over lapsing each other, you can simple drag one of them onto another employee. You should also be able to shrink or expand the assignments like you would normally resize a text area for example.

It would make my life easy if there existed a plugin what can detect x/y position of mouse/elements, easy accessible events on interaction and start end end point of elements when dragging, dropping and resizing. The more specific technical issues like detecting the nearest employee on the y-axis when dragging an element between two employees etc. will be a later concern.

Right now im just looking for a good starting point. Any ideas will gladly be accepted/considered. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the Scheduler RadControl from Telerik. With some modifications it was able to meet my demands.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a straight answer, but I wanted to point out that Flot does support interaction events.  Setting the 'clickable' and 'hoverable' [plot options](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-grid) causes it to produce 'plotclick' and 'plothover' events that should give you enough information to implement drag & drop.

Comment: Yeah im aware of that. But i've read that drag & drop is not supported in flot, so I guess implementing it my self would be almost impossible in a reasonable time horizon. Or what? I cant exactly flotDom.addClass('ui-draggable') ;)

Comment: No, you definitely wouldn't be able to use jQuery draggable, but drag & drop isn't such a complex behavior that you couldn't write it from scratch if there were no other options.